# ScrollView inside custom gesture-based slide-up card causing issues in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, gesture

I've made a minimum reproducible example that I'll paste below. Just plug it into Xcode and you'll see what the deal is. Essentially, I have a custom Slide-Up card. When it's enum position is .top, and I swipe the ScrollView in Xcode simulator, it causes the position of the card to slightly shift. Is there any way to lock the position of the card? Or at the very least make it so having the ScrollView inside of the slide-up card less problematic with swiping gestures?

Content View:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: Alignment.top) {
            Text("test")
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
                .background(Color.red)
            SlideOverCard {
                VStack {
                    ScrollView {
                    VStack {
                        ForEach(1..<100) { _ in
                            Text("test")
                        }
                    }.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
                    }
                    Text("TESTER LINE OF TEXT")
                    Spacer()
                    
                    
                }.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
            }
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.vertical)
    }
}
```

Slide-Up Card:

```
struct SlideOverCard<Content: View> : View {
    @GestureState private var dragState = DragState.inactive
    @State var position = CardPosition.top
    var content: () -> Content
    var body: some View {
    let drag = DragGesture()
            .updating($dragState) { drag, state, transaction in
                state = .dragging(translation: drag.translation)
            }
            .onEnded(onDragEnded)
    return Group {
    Handle()
    self.content()
        }
        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
        .background(Color.white)
        .cornerRadius(10.0)
        .shadow(color: Color(.sRGBLinear, white: 0, opacity: 0.13), radius: 10.0)
        .offset(y: self.position.rawValue + self.dragState.translation.height)
        .animation(self.dragState.isDragging ? nil : .interpolatingSpring(stiffness: 300.0, damping: 30.0, initialVelocity: 10.0))
        .gesture(drag)
    }
    private func onDragEnded(drag: DragGesture.Value) {
    let verticalDirection = drag.predictedEndLocation.y - drag.location.y
    let cardTopEdgeLocation = self.position.rawValue + drag.translation.height
    let positionAbove: CardPosition
    let positionBelow: CardPosition
    let closestPosition: CardPosition
    if cardTopEdgeLocation <= CardPosition.middle.rawValue {
            positionAbove = .top
            positionBelow = .middle
        } else {
            positionAbove = .middle
            positionBelow = .bottom
        }
    if (cardTopEdgeLocation - positionAbove.rawValue) < (positionBelow.rawValue - cardTopEdgeLocation) {
            closestPosition = positionAbove
        } else {
            closestPosition = positionBelow
        }
    if verticalDirection > 0 {
    self.position = positionBelow
        } else if verticalDirection < 0 {
    self.position = positionAbove
        } else {
    self.position = closestPosition
        }
    }
    }
    enum CardPosition: CGFloat {
    case top = 100
    case middle = 500
    case bottom = 850
    }
    enum DragState {
    case inactive
    case dragging(translation: CGSize)
    var translation: CGSize {
    switch self {
    case .inactive:
    return .zero
    case .dragging(let translation):
    return translation
        }
    }
    var isDragging: Bool {
    switch self {
    case .inactive:
    return false
    case .dragging:
    return true
        }
    }
}
```

Handle:

```
struct Handle : View {
    private let handleThickness = CGFloat(5.0)
    var body: some View {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: handleThickness / 2.0)
            .frame(width: 40, height: handleThickness)
            .foregroundColor(Color.secondary)
            .padding(5)
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, ScrollView uses drag gesture and you use drag gesture, so, obviously, they conflict. But it is not clear what did you expect or wanted to achieve?

Comment: @Asperi I just want to have a ScrollView inside of the SlideUpCard that doesn't cause any unexpected behavior. I just want so if I swipe inside of the ScrollView, it doesn't cause a change in position of the SlideUpCard. At the moment, if I swipe inside the ScrollView, sometimes it does change the position of the SlideUpCard. Is there a way to not make the SlideUpCard register the gesture if the gesture is inside the ScrollView?

Comment: @Asperi I made a link to show the glitch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FAnFBsTTdGo&feature=youtu.be

Comment: But in your code ScrollView covers SlideUpCard *completely* (just add border to see), so that's why was my question, because if you give priority to scroll view gesture, you card will stop responding at all, but if both active - there is conflict... so expectations by code are ambiguous.

Comment: @Asperi Yeah, I see what you mean. This is a simplified example of what I'm actually coding. In my actual version, there's a view that is on the slide up card that offsets the ScrollView down by about 200 pixels and you can use the handle (and that 200 pixel section) to control the position of the SlideUpCard. tl; dr in my non simplified code, the scrollview doesn't take up the whole card so it won't be a problem to give priority to scrollview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I managed to reproduce what you meant...

Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

**Update:** - here is found solution

```
ScrollView {
    VStack {
        ForEach(1..<100) { _ in
            Text("test")
        }
    }.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
}
.background(Color.white)             // << make opaque background
.highPriorityGesture(DragGesture())  // << block below DragGesture
```

Also I would consider variant to move drag gesture on "handle" (as you already have it)

```
    return VStack {  // << make it instead of Group
        Handle()
            .gesture(drag)   // << here !!
        self.content()
    }
    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
    .background(Color.white)
    .cornerRadius(10.0)
    .shadow(color: Color(.sRGBLinear, white: 0, opacity: 0.13), radius: 10.0)
    .offset(y: self.position.rawValue + self.dragState.translation.height)
    .animation(self.dragState.isDragging ? nil : .interpolatingSpring(stiffness: 300.0, damping: 30.0, initialVelocity: 10.0))
```